# Can pip install only a specified type of pre-release versions?

Tags: python, pip, state, version, environment

My issue is that, i want to represent 3 environments: dev, int, prod

- On dev I want to install the most up to date dev-version: 1.0.0.dev0
- On int I want to install the most up to date rc-version: 1.0.0.rc0
- On prod I want to install the most up to date production version:
  1.0.0

Is there a way like in these examples?

- `pip install --pre==dev MyModule` should install me 1.0.0.dev0
- `pip install --pre==rc MyModule` should install me 1.0.0.rc0
- `pip install MyModule` should install me 1.0.0

My intention is to have a release-flow like

- 1.0.0.dev0
- 1.0.0.dev1
- 1.0.0.dev2
- 1.0.0.rc0
- 1.0.0.rc1
- 1.0.0

My problem is, that i can represent only 2 states: a pre-release version and one without pre; but i need 3 states.

Is there a way to realize this?
Maybe even without pip?

Comment: You can create multiple python virtual environment for that.

Comment: Right. I got three virtual environments on the client PCs, but i need to control which pypi-package get installed in which venv.

Answer (score 2):

Create three .txt files:

```
touch dev-requirements.txt
touch int-requirements.txt
touch prod-requirements.txt
```

(or however you want to name them), and put in the package versions you want for each environment.

Create a virtual environment for each one:

```
python3 -m venv devenv
source devenv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r dev-requirements.txt
deactivate

python3 -m venv intenv
source intenv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r int-requirements.txt
deactivate

python3 -m venv prodenv
source prodenv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r prod-requirements.txt
```

Then you can simply switch between them depending on which environment you're using.

Alternatively just create one virtual environment and rerun `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` each time you change states, replacing `requirements.txt` with whichever file holds the package versions you want.

Comment: Basically you mean, i should control my 3 environment-setups with 3 configuration files (alias requirements.txt). If any module in the dev-environment gets an update, i need to update the requirments.txt? Is there a way i can just install specially tagged versions, maybe controled by a regex?

Comment: When a module in the dev-environment gets an update, `pip3 freeze > dev-requirements.txt` within the same env will update requirements.txt automatically. About installing specially tagged versions, there may be another solution I haven't seen for managing environments but this would be my best bet.